# Ember Data: Change model data in component and write it back to API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm learning ember.js right now and having trouble to understand how editing model data works. I have a simple model called `singleitem`:

```
export default Model.extend({
    test: DS.attr('string')
});
```

There's a template `singleitem.hbs` that uses a template component `interface_text.hbs` containing this line:

```
<input type="text" value="{{singleitem.test}}" />
```

And a corresponding `interface_text.js` component:

```
export default Component.extend({
    change() {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Whenever I change the content of the `<input>` tag, the `change()` method fires, so this works. But how do I update the model with the new value of the `<input>`?

(My ultimate goal is to write the changed data back to my API. Using `this.test.save();` initiates a `PATCH` request to my API, but sends back the unaltered data. So I think I have to change the model first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to use two-way binding for inputs is to use the input helper provided by ember

To simplify the examples, imagine you are using a component with a property called `test`:

```
// template.hbs
{{input value=this.test}}
```

The second easiest way is to use the `mut` helper with an HTML input tag:

```
// template.hbs
<input type="text" value="{{this.test}}" oninput={{action (mut this.test) value="target.value"}}/>
```

Instead of using the mut helper, you can assign an action to that event:

```
// template.hbs
<input type="text" value="{{this.test}}" oninput={{action "changed"}}/>

// component.js
actions: {
  changed(e) {
    this.set('test', e.target.value);
  }
}
```

In any case, there are some important concepts you need to learn to be able to reach your goal, so I strongly recommend you to read the Ember documentation. There's a great [tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/ember-cli/) that covers all you need to start working with Ember.

Comment: Your "second easiest" way is the one I'm using right now with success. Of course I read the Ember documentation (which is great in most aspects), but was stuck at that point.